# Glimpse EF6 SQL Tab disabled / not Capturing Data Access

Tags: c#

I have used Glimpse before and really liked it so when this new project came up I went right to it. This time however I am using the EF plugin which is new to me. Further the project is broken up into different layers. Overall glimpse is working and it is just the SQL tab that is not active. Logging is turned on with no errors.

My Solution is like so:

1. VS 2015

   1. Repository Project EF 6.0.0.0

      1. Glimpse ADO 1.7.3.0
      2. Glimpse Core 1.8.6.0
   2. MVC & WebAPI Project MVC 5.2.3 WebApi

      1. Glimpse ADO 1.7.3.0
      2. Glimpse ASP.Net
      3. Glimpse Core 1.8.6.0
      4. Glimpse EF6 1.6.5
      5. Glimpse MVC 5

So I am creating a manual SQL connection and most likely that is where my mistake is?

In the repository I establish my context like this:

```
public class PROJDataContext : DbContext, IPROJDataContext
{

    public PROJDataContext() : base(PROJConnection, true)
    { }

    private static GlimpseDbConnection PROJConnection
    {
        get
        {
            //glimpse wrapper
            var conxSection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PROJData"];
            return new GlimpseDbConnection(new SqlConnection(conxSection.ConnectionString));
        }
    }
```

When I fire up the project localhost the SQL tab is disabled. I am assuming this is because the db has not been accessed yet.

I browse to a page that passes request to WebApi. WebApi queries the repository. Data is retrieved from repository and sent back to WebApi which then passes it back to the MVC controller action which then returns a view showing the data.

Glimpse accurately tracks ALL of this except the db portion so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

---

Update...when I wrote this up it was EOD Friday. Talking this through with a colleague today I think I realized the problem. My MVC app which has the Glimpse hooks does **NOT** call SQL instead it calls off to web api and web api calls the repository which has the Glimpse SQL hooks.

Comment: I'm having, I think, the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500420/configuring-glimpse-sql-tab-with-n-layer-architecture 
Maybe you can share your solution? I'm trying to achieve this for 3 days and still no result.