# Configuring Glimpse SQL Tab with N-Layer Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, glimpse

I know it's often question regarding disabled SQL tab in Glimpse but I really can't make it work. 
I have N projects in Solution. Web and Database are seperated.
I installed:

**Glimpse, Glimpse.EF6, Glimpse.MVC, Glimpse.Ado** to Web project, but nothing seems work. I even tried to use GlimpseDbConnection in DbContext - still no result.

```
public CemaDbContext() : base(cemaDbContextConnection, true)
        {
        }

        private static GlimpseDbConnection cemaDbContextConnection
        {
            get
            {
                var contextSection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ManagerConnection"].ConnectionString;
                return new GlimpseDbConnection(new SqlConnection(contextSection));
            }
        }
```

Maybe somebody can guide me thru how to setup SQL Tab?

Comment: do you have any errors or what ?

Comment: @Sampath no errors. Just can't figure out how to configure it

Comment: see this too : http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Manual-ADO-Integration

Comment: I read all of this. Can't figure out how to implement. Do you have code example?

Comment: @Sampath I tried what you suggest, but still no result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that problem was very stupid. I tried to test Glimpse SQL tab with Elmah and not with actual data that was posted or received. When I created View with form with simple data post SQL TAB start working.